# Why the gcc compiler allowed assigning value without giving data type?

Tags: c, gcc

Actually, I had mistakenly typed the below statement but compiler allowed me to execute the statement without throwing any error. My code is,

```
unsigned  i=3;
```

Why the `gcc` allowed assigning value without giving data type? Is that the way what `gcc` will work?

Comment: In this case `unsigned` is the same as `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.2, *Type specifiers*, the list of type specifiers appear as,

> ...
>   — `int`, `signed`, or `signed int`
>   — `unsigned`, or `unsigned int`
>   ...

and the "Semantics" says,

> Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type,...

So, basically, `unsigned` and `unsigned int` refers to the same type and can be considered  interchangeable.

Same logic applies for `int`, `signed` and `signed int`.

So, to answer your question,

> *Why the gcc compiler allowed assigning value without giving data type?*

`unsigned` itself is a type-specifier, which is same as `unsigned int`. So, essentially, the data type is not *missing* here.

Answer (score 4):

Declaring the variable `unsigned` is the same as declaring it `unsigned int` in C. Check this [Wikipedia link on C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) to learn more about it.

So, gcc treats it correctly and compiles fine.

Answer (score 2):

As summarized by [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Integer_types), `signed`, `unsigned`, `short` and `long` all implicitly declare an `int`, unless otherwise specified (e.g. `long double`).